# Serve static files for multiple Flask apps on Nginx with HTTPS

Tags: nginx, flask, https

I'm trying to run multiple Flask apps on Nginx with HTTPS (using Certbot), but I can't get the static files to be served correctly (404). I'm relatively new to Nginx, so I'm not sure if the HTTPS reverse proxy is causing the issues, cause otherwise I think the `location` directives are setup correctly for the static files.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    ssl_ciphers SECRET_STUFF;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:128m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains";
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location /app-one/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    location /app-one/static/ {
        alias /home/pi/flask_test/app_one/static;
    }

    location /app-two/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    location /app-two/static/ {
        alias /home/pi/flask_test/app_two/static;
    }
}
```

And just to clarify, I'm able to view the different apps at `/app-one` and `/app-two`, but the static files (which is currently a single CSS file for testing) isn't coming thru. Here's the Flask app for completeness:

```py
# main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```html
<!-- templates/index.html -->
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>flask app one</h1> <!-- or "flask app two" -->
</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* static/styles.css */
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: You can check nginx error log to see where nginx is actually looking for the static files.

Comment: good call. from the error.log: `open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/styles.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: This is definitely shows your flask app does not add `/app-one` (or `app/two`) URI prefix when generating its links. Generally you should not try to cut this prefix at the nginx level like you doing now using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;` but to setup your flask app to use that prefix in its routes/assets paths and do not change the proxied request URI using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;` instead. Check the [How to mount a Flask app under a URL prefix (or really, any WSGI app)](https://dlukes.github.io/flask-wsgi-url-prefix.html) article.

Comment: never knew about that `SCRIPT_NAME` var, that's super helpful and worked perfectly. also FYI for others, I was able to get by without the `/static` blocks in the Nginx config by running the apps with Docker (but still using `SCRIPT_NAME` for the URL prefix)